# Perl install failing for HTTP::Tiny testing for versions 5.18.2 and 5.20.1

Tags: perl, perlbrew

I'm trying to use Perlbrew to install Perl on a CENTOS Linux server. I've tried installing several versions of 5.16, 5.18. and 5.20, but they all seem to fail the same tests with `HTTP::Tiny`:

```
../cpan/HTTP-Tiny/t/000_load.t .................................... ok
../cpan/HTTP-Tiny/t/001_api.t ..................................... ok
http_proxy URL must be in format http[s]://[auth@]<host>:<port>/
 at t/002_croakage.t line 29.
../cpan/HTTP-Tiny/t/002_croakage.t ................................ 
Dubious, test returned 255 (wstat 65280, 0xff00)
No subtests run 
http_proxy URL must be in format http[s]://[auth@]<host>:<port>/
 at t/003_agent.t line 17.
# Looks like your test exited with 255 before it could output anything.
../cpan/HTTP-Tiny/t/003_agent.t ................................... 
Dubious, test returned 255 (wstat 65280, 0xff00)
Failed 8/8 subtests 
../cpan/HTTP-Tiny/t/010_url.t ..................................... ok
../cpan/HTTP-Tiny/t/020_headers.t ................................. ok
../cpan/HTTP-Tiny/t/030_response.t ................................ ok
../cpan/HTTP-Tiny/t/040_content.t ................................. ok
../cpan/HTTP-Tiny/t/050_chunked_body.t ............................ ok
../cpan/HTTP-Tiny/t/060_http_date.t ............................... ok
http_proxy URL must be in format http[s]://[auth@]<host>:<port>/
 at t/070_cookie_jar.t line 23.
# Looks like your test exited with 255 before it could output anything.
../cpan/HTTP-Tiny/t/070_cookie_jar.t .............................. 
Dubious, test returned 255 (wstat 65280, 0xff00)
Failed 4/4 subtests 
../cpan/HTTP-Tiny/t/100_get.t ..................................... ok
../cpan/HTTP-Tiny/t/101_head.t .................................... ok
../cpan/HTTP-Tiny/t/102_put.t ..................................... ok
../cpan/HTTP-Tiny/t/103_delete.t .................................. ok
../cpan/HTTP-Tiny/t/104_post.t .................................... ok
../cpan/HTTP-Tiny/t/110_mirror.t .................................. ok
../cpan/HTTP-Tiny/t/130_redirect.t ................................ ok
https_proxy URL must be in format http[s]://[auth@]<host>:<port>/
 at t/140_proxy.t line 14.
../cpan/HTTP-Tiny/t/140_proxy.t ................................... 
Dubious, test returned 255 (wstat 65280, 0xff00)
No subtests run 
http_proxy URL must be in format http[s]://[auth@]<host>:<port>/
 at t/141_no_proxy.t line 13.
../cpan/HTTP-Tiny/t/141_no_proxy.t ................................ 
Dubious, test returned 255 (wstat 65280, 0xff00)
No subtests run 
../cpan/HTTP-Tiny/t/150_post_form.t ............................... ok
../cpan/HTTP-Tiny/t/160_cookies.t ................................. ok
../cpan/HTTP-Tiny/t/161_basic_auth.t .............................. ok
../cpan/HTTP-Tiny/t/162_proxy_auth.t .............................. ok
../cpan/HTTP-Tiny/t/170_keepalive.t ............................... ok

Test Summary Report
-------------------
../cpan/HTTP-Tiny/t/002_croakage.t                              (Wstat: 65280 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 255
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
../cpan/HTTP-Tiny/t/003_agent.t                                 (Wstat: 65280 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 255
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 8 tests but ran 0.
../cpan/HTTP-Tiny/t/070_cookie_jar.t                            (Wstat: 65280 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 255
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 4 tests but ran 0.
../cpan/HTTP-Tiny/t/140_proxy.t                                 (Wstat: 65280 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 255
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
../cpan/HTTP-Tiny/t/141_no_proxy.t                              (Wstat: 65280 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 255
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
Files=2405, Tests=699314, 794 wallclock secs (70.76 usr 12.81 sys + 437.06 cusr 53.75 csys = 574.38 CPU)
Result: FAIL
make: *** [test_harness] Error 5
```

I've noticed that `140_proxy.t` is trying to use `http://localhost:8080` as a server test. However, we already have an httpd running on that port. `002_croakage.t` doesn't even contain any tests.

So,

- Are these generally known to be bad tests?
- Is this an issue that others have run into?
- Does this have anything to do with our current service running on port 8080?
- Would there be an issue if I did a *force install*?
- And, why is HTTP::Tiny running tests? It's not a standard Perl module that comes with the installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try without your service running on 8080?  I'm guessing that's the only reason you are getting failures, but the only way to know for certain is to try.

There are a few [failing test reports](http://www.cpantesters.org/distro/H/HTTP-Tiny.html?oncpan=1&distmat=1&version=0.053) but not with the errors you are getting and all relating to connecting to an external server (google, github, twitter).

> And, why is HTTP::Tiny running tests? It's not a standard Perl module that comes with the installation.

It *is* a standard Perl module that comes with the Perl distribution, since Perl 5.13.9.

Comment: You're right. `HTTP:Tiny` is in all of my Perl installs after 5.14. Strange, it's not documented in the official [Perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org) although [perlmodlib](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmodlib) does list it.

Comment: I can't shutdown the service running on Port 8080 to give it a try. During the day, we depend upon it for our build server, and at night, we fetch software to load from our build server. It has to be up 24 hours per day. While I was attempting to install Perlbrew on New Years Day, our IT department installed over 3 dozen packages that had to be fetched from this very server.

Comment: Found the issue: I had `http_proxy` set to `proxy.server.com:3654` and not to `http://proxy.server.com:3654`. This futzed up CPAN's configuration too. However, `wget` itself has no problems with that. I just installed HTTP::Tiny version 0.53 and replaced version 0.43 which came with Perl 5.20.1.